# Why Is FCM Returning SSL Certificate Error?

Tags: java, android, firebase, ssl, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting an SSL Exception when trying to send an message via FCM from my server to the users of my android app. This project is a little old, and has not been maintained for 1.5 years. But before that, this functionality was working fine.

Since then, Google mandated that servers communicating with apps on playstore must have valid SSL. So, I got an SSL certificate from LetsEncrypt and it seems to be working fine (checked for pugme.in here : https://www.digicert.com/help/)

Can anyone help me figure out, how to go about resolving this please?

Cheers

The exception I am getting :

```
ERROR - javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <fcm.googleapis.com> != <*.google.com> OR <*.google.com> OR <*.appengine.google.com> OR <*.bdn.dev> OR <*.cloud.google.com> OR <*.crowdsource.google.com> OR <*.datacompute.google.com> OR <*.google.ca> OR <*.google.cl> OR <*.google.co.in> OR <*.google.co.jp> OR <*.google.co.uk> OR <*.google.com.ar> OR <*.google.com.au> OR <*.google.com.br> OR <*.google.com.co> OR <*.google.com.mx> OR <*.google.com.tr> OR <*.google.com.vn> OR <*.google.de> OR <*.google.es> OR <*.google.fr> OR <*.google.hu> OR <*.google.it> OR <*.google.nl> OR <*.google.pl> OR <*.google.pt> OR <*.googleadapis.com> OR <*.googleapis.cn> OR <*.googlevideo.com> OR <*.gstatic.cn> OR <*.gstatic-cn.com> OR <googlecnapps.cn> OR <*.googlecnapps.cn> OR <googleapps-cn.com> OR <*.googleapps-cn.com> OR <gkecnapps.cn> OR <*.gkecnapps.cn> OR <googledownloads.cn> OR <*.googledownloads.cn> OR <recaptcha.net.cn> OR <*.recaptcha.net.cn> OR <recaptcha-cn.net> OR <*.recaptcha-cn.net> OR <widevine.cn> OR <*.widevine.cn> OR <ampproject.org.cn> OR <*.ampproject.org.cn> OR <ampproject.net.cn> OR <*.ampproject.net.cn> OR <google-analytics-cn.com> OR <*.google-analytics-cn.com> OR <googleadservices-cn.com> OR <*.googleadservices-cn.com> OR <googlevads-cn.com> OR <*.googlevads-cn.com> OR <googleapis-cn.com> OR <*.googleapis-cn.com> OR <googleoptimize-cn.com> OR <*.googleoptimize-cn.com> OR <doubleclick-cn.net> OR <*.doubleclick-cn.net> OR <*.fls.doubleclick-cn.net> OR <*.g.doubleclick-cn.net> OR <doubleclick.cn> OR <*.doubleclick.cn> OR <*.fls.doubleclick.cn> OR <*.g.doubleclick.cn> OR <dartsearch-cn.net> OR <*.dartsearch-cn.net> OR <googletraveladservices-cn.com> OR <*.googletraveladservices-cn.com> OR <googletagservices-cn.com> OR <*.googletagservices-cn.com> OR <googletagmanager-cn.com> OR <*.googletagmanager-cn.com> OR <googlesyndication-cn.com> OR <*.googlesyndication-cn.com> OR <*.safeframe.googlesyndication-cn.com> OR <app-measurement-cn.com> OR <*.app-measurement-cn.com> OR <gvt1-cn.com> OR <*.gvt1-cn.com> OR <gvt2-cn.com> OR <*.gvt2-cn.com> OR <2mdn-cn.net> OR <*.2mdn-cn.net> OR <googleflights-cn.net> OR <*.googleflights-cn.net> OR <admob-cn.com> OR <*.admob-cn.com> OR <*.gstatic.com> OR <*.metric.gstatic.com> OR <*.gvt1.com> OR <*.gcpcdn.gvt1.com> OR <*.gvt2.com> OR <*.gcp.gvt2.com> OR <*.url.google.com> OR <*.youtube-nocookie.com> OR <*.ytimg.com> OR <android.com> OR <*.android.com> OR <*.flash.android.com> OR <g.cn> OR <*.g.cn> OR <g.co> OR <*.g.co> OR <goo.gl> OR <www.goo.gl> OR <google-analytics.com> OR <*.google-analytics.com> OR <google.com> OR <googlecommerce.com> OR <*.googlecommerce.com> OR <ggpht.cn> OR <*.ggpht.cn> OR <urchin.com> OR <*.urchin.com> OR <youtu.be> OR <youtube.com> OR <*.youtube.com> OR <youtubeeducation.com> OR <*.youtubeeducation.com> OR <youtubekids.com> OR <*.youtubekids.com> OR <yt.be> OR <*.yt.be> OR <android.clients.google.com> OR <developer.android.google.cn> OR <developers.android.google.cn> OR <source.android.google.cn>
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to interchange the API key and import the Certs.